# ¿Cómo puedo redireccionar a la penúltima página de donde venía?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con muchas vistas y controladores, y en algunas vistas tengo un link hacia otra, por ejemplo, tengo en la vista index de Breed (breed.index) tengo un link directo que lleva a un create (type.create), el problema que cuando le doy al botón submit del create, este me redirecciona a type.index, ya que por lo que tengo entendido la función back() y previous(), toma la url y le quita hasta el ultimo "/", es decir, si es proyect.app/type/create, al ejecutar back() (en el controlador) o previous() (en un boton en la vista) lleva a proyect.app/type/, y yo busco que se redirija a la vista breed.index que fue de donde partió, pero teniendo en cuenta que si entro al create desde el mismo type.index al ejecutar la función se redirija al anterior y no a breed.index .

Seria como un redireccionamiento dinámico dependiendo de la ruta anterior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel no ofrece directamente una función o helper para redirigir a la «segunda» URL anterior, tendrías que ir almacenando dicha URL en una variable de sesión probablemente, y utilizarla cuando la necesites:

```
// agregar la «nueva URL» a la sesión una vez haya sido utilizada 
// la anterior que estaba almacenada
Session::flash('secondBackUrl', url()->previous());
```

Para utilizarla, sería algo así:

```
$backUrl = session('secondBackUrl') ?? url()->previous();
redirect($backUrl);
```

También podría utilizarse el nombre de la ruta.